# C Language. How to use a string value as delimiter in SSCANF

Tags: c, string, scanf

Is there a way to use a string as a delimiter?
We can use characters as delimiters using sscanf();

Example
I have 
`char url[]="username=jack&pwd=jack123&email=jack@example.com"`

i can use.
`char username[100],pwd[100],email[100];
sscanf(url, "username=%[^&]&pwd=%[^&]&email=%[^\n]", username,pwd,email);`

it works fine for this string.  but for 
`url="username=jack&jill&pwd=jack&123&email=jack@example.com"`

it cant be used...its to remove SQL injection...but i want learn a trick to use 
&pwd,&email as delimiters..not necessarily with sscanf.
Update: Solution doesnt necessarily need to be in C language. I only want to know of a way to use string as a delimiter

Comment: That's one of the reasons for *URL-encoding*. To make sure no special characters are entered as-is in an URL. The problem *can* be solved, but it's not as easy as a single `sscanf` call or even using `strtok` or regular expressions.

Comment: i did use a function to parse and add escape characters like the usual way of removing SQL injection...But i wish there are ways to use a string as a delimiter it will save a lot of time..i could probably make a custom function , not sure though. .i wanted to know if it is possible in C or any other language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **code your own [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)**. In many cases, representing in memory the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) you have parsed is useful. But do specify and document your input language (perhaps using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation).

Your input language (which you have not defined in your question) seems to be similar to the [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) type [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type) used in  [HTTP POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) requests. So you might look, at least for inspiration, into the source code of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) libraries related to HTTP server processing (like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)) and HTTP client processing (like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)).

You could read an entire line with [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (or perhaps `fgets`) then parse it appropriately. [`sscanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) with `%n`, or [`strtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) might be useful, but you can also parse the line "manually" (consider using e.g. your [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)). You might use [`strchr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)  or [`strstr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html) also.

BTW, in many cases, using common textual representations like [JSON](http://json.org/), [YAML](http://yaml.org/), XML can be helpful, and you can easily find many libraries to handle them.

Notice also that strings can be processed as `FILE*` by using [`fmemopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) and/or [`open_memstream`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html).

You could use parser generators such as [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) (with [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex)).

In some cases, regular expressions could be useful. See [regcomp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html) and friends.

So what you want to achieve is quite easy to do and standard practice. But you need more that just [`sscanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) and you may want to combine several things.

Many external libraries (e.g. [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) from GTK) provide some parsing. And you should care about UTF-8 (today, you have [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)).

On Linux, if permitted to do so, you might use [GNU readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/) instead of  [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) when you want interactive input (with editing abilities and autocompletion). Then take inspiration from the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (or of [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), if interested by C++).

If you are unfamiliar with usual parsing techniques, **read** a good book such as **the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_(computer_science))**. Most large programs deal somewhere with parsing, so you need to know how that can be done.

Comment: yes i want to make a function to replace sscanf in the above function and i can make it and especially because the url is fixed it is easy to do so..i

Comment: So just code that, not a big deal. But do spend several days reading books about parsing (and compiling). They are well established techniques for that.

Comment: in POSIX and awk yoy can use string as delimiters..so i was hoping C might have implemented something similar too

Comment: Standard C offer limited string processing, but writing your own, or finding some external library, is very common practice. BTW [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) coded in C so you could study its source code and be inspired by it.

Comment: Most large programs in C have some parsing inside. That is why reading a good book about parsing is so important. Established techniques exist.

Comment: what i did was..replaced string and added a new delimiter..for that particular question.. a symbol which is illegal...like ' : ' with '&'..this symbol could be used as username...so i just changed.."&pwd" to ":pwd" and changed the delimiter..i mean we need to make specific rules and make some characters illegal use

Comment: I'm not sure that changing the syntax is wise. Your initial syntax is standard `x-www-form-urlencoded` but you new one is not. And how do you escape `:` ?

Comment: its just i copy the original string replace the `&` before the credentials with `:`..since it is not used in the user input..illegal for the particular problem. I am just using `:` as the delimiter with `sscanf` instead of `&`.